# React/Redux: Need to build a React component with Redux that dynamically generates additional dropdowns based on initial dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to build a React Component with a Redux action and reducer to handle a selection from a dropdown. Something along the lines of an action `UPDATE_NUMBER_OF_DROPDOWNS` that will act as the listener on the dropdown to trigger an action/reducer flow. The current layout will be a single dropdown with a set of options for 0, 1, 5 and 13 and depending on what number the user selects that many rows with dropdown fields of their own will populate. So if a user selects 5, an additional section will appear below with 5 rows of fields called Justification each with their own dropdown that lists a subset of options. I'm new to Redux so I'm trying to determine how to accomplish this, but I think I need I've included the base state of my React component below
`Select Form Component`

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Col, Row, Collapse } from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'
import icon from '../../assets/caretDown.svg'
import Button from '../elements/Button'

const { Panel } = Collapse

const ConfigurationOptions = () => (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col span={12}>
        <StyledCollapse>
          <Panel
            header="Configure Form"
            key="1"
          >
            <div>
              <Row>
                <Col span={12}>
                  <p>Form Fields</p>
                </Col>
                <Col span={12}>
                  <CustomSelect>
                    <option>none</option>
                    <option>5 Form Fields</option>
                    <option>10 Form Fields</option>
                    <option>13 Form Fields</option>
                  </CustomSelect>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <div>
                <StyledH1>Form Field Justification</StyledH1>
                <Row>
                  <Col
                    span={8}
                    offset={16}
                  >
                    <ButtonContainer>
                      <Button
                        type="primary"
                        Apply to all
                      </Button>
                    </ButtonContainer>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <br />
                <Row>
                  <Col span={12}>Field #1</Col>
                  <Col span={12}>
                    <CustomSelect>
                      <option>Select Justification</option>

                    </CustomSelect>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Panel>
        </StyledCollapse>
      </Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
)

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`

const StyledH1 = styled.h1`
  font-weight: 700;
`

const CustomSelect = styled.select`
  padding: 5px 45px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url(${icon});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 8px center;
`

const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
`

// Use for Show/Hide link
/* <Button type="link">APPLY TO ALL</Button> */

export default ConfigurationOptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the missing pieces for you are the `Array.map()` and `onChange()` methods.

1. You can use some sort of data structure to store the values of your options, then use `map` to dynamically build your HTML.
2. You can detect changing the calue of `<CustomSelect>` by defining a local method that handles the user's progress (i.e. which of the selection elements are rendered).

Of course you have to define `onChoosingOption` and `this.state.value`, but eventually it'd look something like this:

```
const firstLevelOptions = [0, 5, 10, 13];

<CustomSelect onChange={this.onChoosingOption} value={this.state.value}>
  {
    firstLevelOptions.map(x => <option value={x}>
                                 {x === 0 ? 'none' : x + ' Form Fields'}
                               </option>)
  }
/*
Results in
  <option value="0">none</option>
  <option value="5">5 Form Fields</option>
  <option value="10">10 Form Fields</option>
  <option value="13">13 Form Fields</option>
*/
</CustomSelect>
```

And then you can use pretty much the same thing with the next levels.

Comment: I would normally do it that way but I need to create a set of Redux actions/reducers for that functionality because I'll be storing the state of the dropdown in the store.

Comment: I'm afraid you'd have to define all the redux configurations in advance, as they can't be defined dynamically. Still, I think the main challenge is to define the data structure that will wrap your form's state

Comment: I realized that as soon as I responded haha. I updated my original question to include a little more clarity in terms of what actions/reducers I'll need to create. Hopefully that helps